# Schedule daily startup of an Azure virtual machine using logicapp template

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I created a logicapp in Azure using Microsoft's own "Start Virtual Machine" template but it is not working and showing the error: "ActionConditionFailed. The execution of template action 'Notify_on_success' is skipped: the 'runAfter' condition for action 'Start_virtual_machine' is not satisfied. Expected status values 'Succeeded' and actual value 'Failed'.". What I am doing wrong?

[This is the logicapp setup using Microsoft's "Start Virtual Machine" template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN8je.png)

[This the message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMjeD.png)

Comment: So why did the previous step fail? Do you have a message or something?

Comment: What is the error message in Start Virtual Machine step or action

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively I would suggest you to create  actions in the design manually like below as we do not know what is the error:

[image]

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]